# Data Migration Tool Issue( magento 1.9 to magento 2.3 )

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration

I was added new product and update the details and search the product  from frontend, but it shows error in log file "No linked stock found"   also found same issue while adding Stores > Inventory > Stocks  details to all websites (multi store) and hit save, gives error in log  file

> "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table  'magento2.3.inventory_stock_2' doesn't exist"

and  in interface its shows like this

> "Can not save link  related to Default Source or Default Stock"

Comment: Are you solve this

Comment: <steps mode="settings">
    <step title="Settings Step">
    <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
    <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
     </step></steps>                                                                                                            pls update above details under "settings section" of the  config.xml file